# react-router: Showing/Hiding a component based on Path matched

Tags: react-router

I am using react router v4 and react v16. There is a need where some components be mounted only once (when rendered first time), but rendered based on the Router path matches. (One such use case is to show a report for a menu item click, and at a later invocation, the report shown need not be fetched again).

Using Switch or just plain Route component -- the component gets unmounted, when that component is not in the path.

Currently, I am doing like this (which solves the issue in hand):

```
<main>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <WrapRoute exact path="/about" component={About} />
</main>

const WrapRoute = ({path, ...rest}) => (
  <div style={{display: rest.location.pathname == path ? "block" : "none"}}>
    <Route {...rest} />
  </div>
)
```

But I don't think directly verifying the location.pathname is a good idea. I would like 'Route' component to handle this.

I would like suggestions in handling this scenario (in such a way that the component is not re-mounted again). A solution or a different pattern, to address this is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I am not sure, if there is a better pattern, that can solve this -- the following code is better than what is provided.

**Update:**

Though one could call matchPath function, I just realized that calling "children" parameter is a better option.

```
  <Route exact path="/dc/:id" children={({ match, ...rest }) => (
    <div style={{display: match && match.params.id === id.toString()
      ? "block"
      : "none"
    }}>
      <Component {...rest} match={match} />
    </div>
  )} />
```

**Earlier solution:**

matchPath function from react-router can do exactly identify -- whether this path will get matched or not.

```
<main>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <WrapRoute exact path="/about" component={About} />
</main>

......

import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

const WrapRoute = ({path, exact, ...rest}) => (
  <div style={{display: matchPath(rest.location.pathname, { path, exact })
    ? "block"
    : "none"
  }}>
    <Route {...rest} />
  </div>
)
```